# react-native redux nested array reducer

Tags: javascript, arrays, redux

I am learning to write reducers for arrays. For example, one of the reducers changes array elements from integers to arrays.

#### Original state:

```
[0, 3, 5, 3, 9, 8]
```

#### Action:

```
case ADD_NEST:
      return state.map(i => [i, action.payload]);
```

#### New state:

```
[[0, 0], [3, 0], [5, 0], [3, 0], [9, 0], [8, 0]]
```

I'm trying to write a reducer that would change the second element of sub-arrays based on the condition of the first one. (*eg, if the first element of the subarray is greater than `3`, change the second element to `1`*).

```
[[0, 0], [3, 0], [5, 1], [3, 0], [9, 1], [8, 1]]
```

so far I have (*not much as I'm stuck*):

```
case SET_BIT:
      return state.map(i => (i[0] > 3 ? ??? : i));
```

Thank you for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
case SET_BIT:
  return state.map(i => (i[0] > 3 ? [i[0], i[1] + 1] : i));
```

Although, that's a bit weird/dangerous. What happens if `SET_BIT` gets dispatched when your state of that reducer is still a flat array? Then the above code will crash. Then you would have to do something like:

```
case SET_BIT:
  return state.map(i => (
    Array.isArray(i) && i[0] > 3
      ? [i[0], i[1] + 1]
      : i
  ));
```

I don't know the details of what you are trying to do here, but generally speaking I think it's best to keep the structure of the state of a reducer consistent. I tend to avoid nested structures in the state of my redux store because I try to keep the state of my redux store as normalized as I can. That makes reducers a lot easier to maintain. If I need to nest stuff for my views I usually do that in the selectors.

But again, I lack context, so not sure if any of this advice is relevant to you. :-)

Comment: Thanks - I'll try it when I get back from work. Basically, I'm testing out simple scenarios to learn as what I really try to do is I have an array of numbers (which are displayed on a grid) but then I need to indicate if each grid element/number is displayed (on/off) - that's why I thought that would be the best way of representing it The initial state would be as follows where all the numbers are hidden: [[number, 0], [number, 0], [number, 0],.....] so when I want to display any of the elements I'll just change the 0 to 1. Is that the best way of organising it?